# 2007 Mark V Golf Electrical issue

Tags: electrical, starting, vw, golf, no-crank-no-start

My mark v golf is having issues. The car seems fine with key in, and when ignition turned on its still okay, then when you go to start it, there is almost clicking noises coming from the steering column area. The car doesnt even attempt to turn over, and all the electrical systems wont work. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you tried with a fully charged battery? Either charing original or a spare?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my MK6 Golf. The problem was the battery. It was almost empty after the car sat some time. The not working electronics are also a hint in this direction.

Try charging the battery before replacing anything, sometimes this helps. If its defective you need a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem on VW's.  It's time to change the ignition key and cylinder, which is a relatively simple task if you're handy.  If you wait until the key won't turn to the "start" position, you'll be in for a much bigger repair.

Here are [the instructions](https://www.pelicanparts.com/techarticles/Volkswagen_Golf_GTI_Mk_V/91-BODY-Replacing_Your_Ignition_Switch_and_Lock_Cylinder/91-BODY-Replacing_Your_Ignition_Switch_and_Lock_Cylinder.htm).